# Mongodb - $Text return documents where all the words is in the document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is the data in the my mongodb

```
db.test.insert([
 { "modelo" : "S10 P-Up Executive 2.4 MPFI F.Power CD" },
 { "modelo" : "SANDERO STEPWAY Hi-Power 1.6 8V 5p" },
 { "modelo" : "Gol (novo) 1.6 Power/Highi T.Flex 8v 4P" }
 ])
```

There is a text index for this document.

```
db.test.createIndex( { modelo: "text" } )
```

This query bring all the data, what is correct.
    db.test.find( { $text: { $search: "Gol power" } } )

However, I would like to know if there is an way to bring the documents where both words is inside. For this example, instead to return all, it would return just one:

```
   { "modelo" : "Gol (novo) 1.6 Power/Highi T.Flex 8v 4P" }
```

I was trying to do it using the aggregate instead of find. However I didn't have success.
Any suggestion how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Approach 1:

Default values given in $search will be considered for OR operator and that is the reason you are getting all records, we need to give the query as shown below to make the $search to take the given words for AND operator

```
db.test.find( { $text: { $search: "\"Gol\" power" } } )
```

Result is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a20fa66bf339f14930eb0ae"), "modelo" : "Gol (novo) 1.6 Power/Highi T.Flex 8v 4P" }
```

If the $search string includes a phrase and individual terms, text search will only match the documents that include the phrase. More specifically, the search performs a logical AND of the phrase with the individual terms in the search string. Please see [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

> Approach 2:

Alternatively, we can use achieve it in other way by using [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). It is much slower, as it does full collection scan, but it gives you more flexibility, e.g. to take into account order of words.

Sample query to retrieve the required result, where `Gol` appears strictly before `power`:

```
db.test.find({modelo:{$regex: /Gol.*power/, $options: "si"}});
```

Result is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a20fa66bf339f14930eb0ae"), "modelo" : "Gol (novo) 1.6 Power/Highi T.Flex 8v 4P" }
```

Reason for db.test.find( { $text: { $search: "Gol power" } } ) bringing all data is takes the words with OR condition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The approach 1 worked for me. I change for the database I have and if I want both words, I need to input \" before and after for each word. Eg: ( { $text: { $search: "\"Gol\" \"power\"" } }, {modelo:1, _id:0} ).